# Using svn2git to convert a local Tortoise SVN repo

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I'm trying to convert a Tortoise SVN repo which lives on a partition which is shared by my Windows/ Ubuntu dual boot machine to a git repo.  I've created a new directory for the git repo, and tried `svn2git svn://media/mpoint/School/OLD_SVN_DIR` on the Ubuntu machine with no luck.

I've seen lots of examples where the SVN repo is server based, but I haven't seen any local examples.  IE: `svn2git svn://localhost/name-of-repo`.  If it helps, on the Windows side (where the SVN repo was made) the address was `https:/John-T60/svn/OLD_SVN_DIR/`.  I've tried this using the command `svn2git https://John-T60/svn/OLD_SVN_DIR` with no luck.

My SVN repo isn't very complicated, maybe 50-100 commits and just the master branch.  Any examples?

Comment: Does your repository have trunk/branches/tags structure?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting, if any?

Comment: What does "I [..] tried `svn2git` [..] with no luck" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply workarounding this issues: Export your subversion repository via

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/your/repo > yourreporname.dump
```

temporarily install VisualSVN (which is a very easy to setup and use SVN repository), import your dump using their convenient GUI and proceed to convert your repository to Git as regular remote SVN repository.

Comment: ...and then there was that time I had 100 repos to process

Comment: You have 100, file-based SVN Repos? Really? If no you can use the simple "git svn init -s repourl" and "git svn fetch" in a batchfile.

Comment: I have at least 40, but in searching this I did read a guy who was dealing with 122.